# Variable not updating its value

Tags: javascript

```
var canAssignMultiple="true";
var canWithdrawMultiple="true";

function onCheckUncheck() 
{
    if($(':checkbox[name^="checkedRecords"]:checked').length>0)
    {
        $("input[name='checkedRecords']:checked").each(function()
        {
            debugger;
            var canAssign = $(this).attr("canAssign").toLowerCase();
            var canWithdraw = $(this).attr("canWithdraw").toLowerCase();
            canAssignMultiple= canAssignMultiple && canAssign;
            canWithdrawMultiple= canWithdrawMultiple && canWithdraw;
            if (canAssignMultiple == "false") 
                $("#assaignbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            else 
                $("#assaignbutton").removeAttr("disabled");

            if (canWithdrawMultiple == "false") 
                $("#withdrawbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            else
                $("#withdrawbutton").removeAttr("disabled");
        });
    }          
    else
    {
        $("#assaignbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#withdrawbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

The variable canAssignMultiple is becoming true when each() function is called the second time though its value has changed to false in the first iteration.It should retain its value evrytime the loop runs.How to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid the string `"false"` is truthy. Perhaps you are using `canAssign=false` in your HTML?

Comment: Do you mean `canAssignMultiple` is becoming the string `'true'`?

Comment: As Jan alluded to, please show us a sample of your HTML, so we can see what the values of the `canAssign` attribute are.

Comment: `"true" && "false"` is (confusingly enough) `"false"` even if `"false" && "true"` is (luckily) `"true"`

Answer (score 0):

`boolean` (false, true) values are different than `strings` ("false", "true")

try

```
var canAssignMultiple = true;
var canWithdrawMultiple = true;

function onCheckUncheck() {
    if ($(':checkbox[name^="checkedRecords"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $("input[name='checkedRecords']:checked").each(function() {
            debugger;
            var canAssign = $(this).attr("canAssign").toLowerCase() == "true"; // make this a boolean expression
            var canWithdraw = $(this).attr("canWithdraw").toLowerCase() == "true"; // make this a boolean expression
            canAssignMultiple = canAssignMultiple && canAssign;
            canWithdrawMultiple = canWithdrawMultiple && canWithdraw;
            if (canAssignMultiple === false) $("#assaignbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled"); // use false (instead of "false")
            else $("#assaignbutton").removeAttr("disabled");
            if (canWithdrawMultiple === false) $("#withdrawbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled"); // use false (instead of "false")
            else $("#withdrawbutton").removeAttr("disabled");
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#assaignbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#withdrawbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}​
```

left comments where changes were made

Comment: Your explanation is good. I'm afraid your fix won't suffice, though.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the strings `"true"` and `"false"` do not function the same as the boolean values `true` and `false`. If you try to use a string in an `if` statement or with a logical operator such as `&&`, the string is converted to a boolean; and all non-empty strings are converted to `true` (i.e. they are "truthy"). That means the string `"false"` will work the opposite of how you expect, e.g. in `("false" && x)` or in `if ("false") {...}`.

One way to fix your code is to change this line

```
               canAssignMultiple = canAssignMultiple && canAssign;
```

to convert `canAssign` to a boolean in an explicit and correct way:

```
               canAssignMultiple = canAssignMultiple && (canAssign == "true");
```

Then the `&&` operator will work correctly, and `canAssignMultiple` will hold an actual boolean value.

And (as @mdmullinax noted, but I would do it differently) once canAssignMultiple is actually a boolean, you can change your `if` statements to treat them as such:

```
if (canAssignMultiple == "false")
```

should become

```
if (!canAssignMultiple)
```

And similarly with the corresponding `withdraw` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Does your HTML look like this?

```
<input canAssign="false" ...>
<input canAssign="true" ...>
```

If so, and you can't change the HTML, I suggest changing this:

```
canAssign = $(this).attr("canAssign").toLowerCase()
```

to this (to work with booleans from then on):

```
canAssign = $(this).attr("canAssign") == "true"
```

and this:

```
if(canAssignMultiple == "false")
```

to this (since it is a real boolean now):

```
if(canAssignMultiple)
```

If you *can* change HTML, I suggest you do it the HTML5-compliant way. First, all of your made up attributes should be prefixed `data-`. You can also change camelCase to hyphen-case. JQuery, when loading your data-attributes, will then [perform the conversion](http://api.jquery.com/data/) from string if possible:

```
<input data-can-assign="false" ...>
<input data-can-assign="true" ...>
```

then jQuery will give you the boolean you want from this call:

```
canAssign = $(this).data("canAssign")
```

---

Of course, the same fix should be applied to all other string pseudo-booleans (that don't quite work with the boolean operators) as well.

The reason is: `"false"` is not exactly `false`. `"false" && x` will evaluate to `x` (not to `"false"` as you expect). On the other hand, `false && x` will evaluate to `false`.